# Facing Issues in Einstein Next Best Action

Tags: aura, einstein, screen-flow, einstein-next-best-action

I am facing an issue in Einstein Next Best Action, I am unable to get a value of the input variable "isRecommendationAccepted" in my flow while accepting or rejecting the recommendation.
Also, we need to fire the flow on rejection as well but could not find any option to set this setting as it is not available publicly.

for ref: https://unofficialsf.com/the-next-best-actions-lightning-component/

I am unable to find any official documentation on lighting:nextBestActions component.

I am using screen flow which has a custom Aura component that uses lighting:nextBestActions component.